# SELECT Query for a Bill of Materials

Tags: sql, sql-server-2008

Our Bill of Materials table has 3 main columns: Part Number, Parent Part, and Level Code (0 being no parent, 3 being a child of a child of a child, etc).

I'd am trying to query based on a single part and get all of its children and their children, so on.

Its seems so simple but I have been struggling with this one. Anyone have a solution they can offer?

As always, I appreciate the help.

**Per Randy's request, here is some more info:**

PARPRT = Parent
COMPRT = Component

In the screen shot, all the component parts are part of the Bill of Materials for '101002'.

Later down the table, you will see each of those components in COMPRT listed in the PARPRT column with the components that make each of them up.

I want to query the BOM for '101002' and not only get the 4 parts in COMPRT where PARPRT = '101002', but also their COMPRTs and so on.

[image: screenshot]

Comment: You haven't provided nearly enough information for anyone to give you a helpful answer. Please post the schema of the tables involved, and the Select statement that you've been working on.

Comment: What is the maximum level?  If large, you will need to use recursive CTEs for this type of query.

Comment: Since you are on SQL Server 2008, you may want to consider using a Hierarchy ID in that table.  This article shows how to use it with a BOM:  http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/magazine/cc794278.aspx

Comment: Have a look at recursive CTE's: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms186243(v=sql.105).aspx

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thank you for those who suggested CTE's. That was exactly what I was looking for.

Here is the query I ended up with after some trial and error.

> USE PartDatabase
>   GO
>   DECLARE @TheSinglePart CHAR(30) = '100001';
>   WITH BOM (PARPRT_02, COMPRT_02, QTYPER_02)
>   AS
>   (
>   -- Anchor member definition
>   SELECT e.PARPRT_02, e.COMPRT_02, e.QTYPER_02
>       FROM dbo.Product_Structure AS e
>       WHERE e.PARPRT_02 = @TheSinglePart 
>   UNION ALL
>   -- Recursive member definition
>   SELECT e.PARPRT_02, e.COMPRT_02, e.QTYPER_02
>       FROM dbo.Product_Structure AS e
>       INNER JOIN BOM AS d
>           ON e.PARPRT_02 = d.COMPRT_02
>   )
>   SELECT * 
>   FROM BOM;